# Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] osgi.wiring.package;

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to add jetty client library and use it it one of Bnd OSGi bundle based project. With added libraries Code is comping/building But when I run "Bnd OSGi Run Launcher" I see below error:

> could not resolve the bundles:
>   [com.project.examples-2.0.1.201605061319Unresolved constraint in
>   bundle com.project.examples [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing
>   requirement [8.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.client)(version>=9.3.0)(!(version>=10.0.0)))
>   ]

I have added required jetty client jar file in Java Build path libraries, have also added entry in classpath.  Still getting this error.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the Jetty version correct (at least 9.3.0 and less than 10.0.0)?

Comment: my jetty version is jetty-9.3.8.v20160314

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Jetty Client bundle into your runtime OSGi framework.

From your question, it seems you have only added it to your build path or classpath.

Comment: I have downloaded http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.3.6.v20151106/ jetty bundle for client files org.eclipse.jetty.client_9.3.6.v20151106.jar and org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.3.6.v20151106.jar. I am not sure how to install them in my project

Comment: It depends how you are running OSGi. How do you put your own bundle into the OSGi Framework? Just do the same thing with the Jetty bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org) as a starting point for your application then you can start using the Bndtools resolver. This will make these kind of problems more easier to detect and handle. See the [Quick Start](http://enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html) tutorial for how to build an app using the resolver.